# Using flask_login session with jinja2 templates

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2, flask-login

I have simple jinja2 template with registration/login links, I should hide them when user logged in, I also use flask_login module for this stuff.

Question is: **How should I identify is user logged in in jinja2 templates?**

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Flask-Login adds the `current_user` variable to your templates:

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    ...
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

They mention this briefly in [the documentation](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#login-example).

Comment: [Flask-login docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) do specify that

 `You can then access the logged-in user with the current_user proxy, which is available in every template`

Comment: Now is {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}

Comment: Note that when using `{{ current_user.is_authenticated }}` in javascript, that the value returned is not understood and must be put in a a string such as `"{{ current_user.is_authenticated }}"`. Came across this when validating onclick ajax requests for logged in users.