# Check if Flask-HTTPAuth is authenticated inside view

Tags: python, flask, flask-httpauth

I'm using Flask-HTTPAuth for authentication. I want to display different data from a view depending on if the request was authenticated or not. Decorating the view with `auth.login_required` only shows it to authenticated users. How can I test if the request was authenticated with Flask-HTTPAuth?

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route("/clothesInfo")
@auth.login_required
def show_info():
    return jsonify(blah blah blah)
```

Comment: I don't know if you can do this with flask-httpauth as you need a object passed to your template that contains the information if the user is authenticated. I know you definitely can do this with [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361151/using-flask-login-session-with-jinja2-templates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is actually very easy to implement. In your `verify_password` callback, you will get username and password set to `''` when the user does not provide credentials. You can still return `True` from that function, and that will allow the anonymous user to access the endpoint.

The following example demonstrates this technique:

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    if username == '' or password == '':
        # anonymous user, we still let them in
        g.current_user = None
        return True
    g.current_user = my_verify_function(username, password)
    return g.current_user is not None

@app.route("/clothesInfo")
@auth.login_required
def show_info():
    if g.current_user:
        # prepare data for authenticated users here
        pass
    else:
        # prepare data for anonymous users here
        pass
    return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: This answer is now outdated. Use `optional` parameter. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67606903/4653485).

Answer (score 3):

You can decorate a function that returns `None` with `login_required`. Calling it while not authenticated will return an error response, calling it while authenticated will return `None`.

```
# a dummy callable to execute the login_required logic
login_required_dummy_view = auth.login_required(lambda: None)

def is_authenticated():
    try:
        # default implementation returns a string error
        return login_required_dummy_view() is None
    except HTTPException:
        # in case auth_error_callback raises a real error
        return False

@app.route('/info')
def info():
    if is_authenticated():
        # logged in view

    else:
        # basic view
```

See also [Default login_required rather than adding decorator everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30761002/400617).

Answer (score 1):

Things are simpler since April 2020.

Flask-HTTPAuth 4.0.0 added `optional` argument to `login required` to do exactly this.

From [the docs](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_httpauth.HTTPBasicAuth.login_required):

> An optional optional argument can be set to True to allow the route to execute also when authentication is not included with the request, in which case auth.current_user() will be set to None. Example:
>
> ```py
> @app.route('/private')
> @auth.login_required(optional=True)
> def private_page():
>     user = auth.current_user()
>     return "Hello {}!".format(user.name if user is not None else 'anonymous')
> ```